# Change page, the enhancement of the previous page is removed

Tags: jquery-mobile

page1 header:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-a">
<h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Foo</h1>
</div>
```

after changing to page2,

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change",  "#page2", { } );
```

page1 header becomes: (class removed)

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
<h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Foo</h1>
</div>
```

After going back to page1,

```
$.mobile.back();
```

the page1 header is not enhanced.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Both pages are static? Are you injecting the page dynamically?

Comment: the two pages are dynamically added by ajax, the main page is not listed above. thanks.

Comment: Please post the code of how you create the pages and how do you navigate back to page1.

Comment: Sorry for posting the question without fully debugging our own code first. Found the issue. Ajax update the header incorrectly when navigating to the next page, which removes the enhancement of previous page header. Thanks.